# Set button state to active with jQuery

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I need to get my buttons to become `:active` state when some keyboard button is pressed and not just when clicked.

here is my code... thanks in advance.

Script :

```
$(document).on('keypress', function (e) {
    var tag = e.target.tagName.toLowerCase();
    if (e.which === 119 && tag != 'input' && tag != 'textarea')
        $('#forward').click();
    if (e.which === 115 && tag != 'input' && tag != 'textarea')
        $('#back').click();
    if (e.which === 97 && tag != 'input' && tag != 'textarea')
        $('#left').click();
    if (e.which === 100 && tag != 'input' && tag != 'textarea')
        $('#right').click();
});

$(function () {
    $("#forward").click(function () {
        $.ajax('/forward');
    });
    $("#back").click(function () {
        $.ajax('/back');
    });
    $("#left").click(function () {
        $.ajax('/left');
    });
    $("#right").click(function () {
        $.ajax('/right');
    });
});
```

HTML :

```
<ul class="button-list">
 <li>
    <button id="forward">W</button>
 </li>
 <li>
    <button id="back">S</button>
 </li>
 <li>
    <button id="left">A</button>
 </li>
 <li>
    <button id="right">D</button>
 </li>
</ul>
```

...................................................................................

Comment: you mean the :active state as css pseudo class?

Comment: Sorry, yes that is correct.

Comment: At the moment the css animation doesn't run on keypress.

Answer (score 8):

You have to create a `class` which `style` is the same of the `:active` state of the `button` so :

**General example**

```
.buttonclass:active , .activated { /* somestyle */ }

$('.buttonclass').on('click', function(){ 
  $(this).addClass('activated'); //eventually removeClass of some previous class
  //other stuff
});
```

**Your CODE**

**CSS**

```
#forward:active, .forwardactivate{}
#back:active, .backactivate{}
```

Or if you have a `ul li button` `style` then you have to do:

```
ul li button:active, .activatebutton {} /* style*/
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
     $(function() {
            $("#forward").click(function() {
              $.ajax('/forward');
              if($(this).hasClass('forwardactivate'))
                $(this).removeClass('forwardactivate'); //change with .activatebutton
              else      
               $(this).addClass('forwardactivate');
             });

            //etc
     });
```

Comment: however now I have the below but it stays on the activated class after I have pressed it.
 

  `$.ajax('/forward');
  $('button').removeClass('active');
  $(this).addClass('active');`

Comment: Edited. If you think is the right answer, please accept it :)

Answer (score 3):

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
$("ul > li button").click(function () {
        $('ul > li button').removeClass('active');
        $(this).addClass('active');
    });
});
```

```css
ul > li button.active{
background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul class="button-list">
 <li>
    <button id="forward">W</button>
 </li>
 <li>
    <button id="back">S</button>
 </li>
 <li>
    <button id="left">A</button>
 </li>
 <li>
    <button id="right">D</button>
 </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont know what did you mean about "Set Button to .Active" but for example you can trigger its click by this code :

```
$(document).keypress(function(e){

    if(e.keychar == 'w')
    {
        $("#forward").trigger('click');
        //You can do any thing here ex. "set button state Active"
        //$("#forward").addClass('active');
    }
    else if(e.keychar == 's')
        $("#back").trigger('click');
    else if(e.keychar == 'a')
        $("#left").trigger('click');
    else if(e.keychar == 'd')
        $("#right").trigger('click');

});
```

Answer (score 0):

can't you add .active class according to the page... say if you are on /forward add `.active` to forward... or you can do it like this too:

```
$("#forward").click(function() {
      $.ajax('/forward');
      $('button').removeClass('active');
      $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

Comment: 'button' selector should be '.button'