# Can a button’s :active CSS property be activated with a jQuery .click()?

Tags: jquery, css, button

This is a question which has been bothering me for a long time.

I have assigned properties under a `button:active` in my CSS. Thus, when a user clicks a button on the page, the button will assume the active properties, then revert back to its original look after the click event. e.g.

```
#start:active {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background-color: mediumblue;
  transform: translateY(3px);
  box-shadow: none;
}
```

On the same page, I use jQuery to click buttons on keydown events. e.g.

```
$(document).keydown(function(e) {
  if (e.keyCode === 70) {
    $("#start").click();
  } 
})
```

However, using the jQuery .click() method only simulates clicking a button without the aspect of my CSS active properties. I figure I could use the `.addClass()` method and set a timeout for `removeClass()` in my keydown event, but is there an easier way to accomplish this and take advantage of the CSS active?

Comment: See [Set button state to active with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18484387/924299).

Comment: That answer is what I felt was the logical solution, using `addClass()` and then `removeClass()` after some time.

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of using `:active`, before doing `click()` using jQuery, you can just toggle/add a class like `button--active`!

`$("#start").addClass("button--active");
$("#start").click();`

Comment: Thanks—as mentioned in the last paragraph of my question, I figured `addClass()` would be the way to go. It doesn’t seem like there’s a way to quickly activate then remove the `:active` property (as would happen with a physical click) without using an `addClass` (where the class has identitical properties as the :active) then `removeClass` on a timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use `trigger()` method:

`$("#start").trigger('focus')`